# Por que me aparece No such file or directory? ( haciendo un slideshow)

Tags: python, archivo

lo que estoy haciendo es un slideshow, que lo que hace es que las imagenes vallan rotando. Todo funciona bien pero cuando rota 1 vez a la segunda rotacion me da este
error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'vertical1-2.png'
Y no entiendo por qué si ya me esta mostrando alguna de las imagenes .png y .gif, por lo que uso dos tipos de formato en las imagenes es para que me seleccione todas las imagenes de una carpeta de un formato y todas del otro así puedo ponerlo en diferentes Labels para tener 2 slideshows. Tambien aparece algo de esto sobre el PIL: line 2912, in open fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb").
No se por que me da este error pero si alguien lo sabe que me responda, gracias.
Aquí dejo el código por si os ayuda.

```
    import os
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import *
    from itertools import cycle
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from os import *
    from wand.image import  Color
    from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
    class Slideshow(tkinter.Tk):
       
        def __init__(self, images, imagenes2, slide_interval):
           
            tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.geometry("1300x1300+0+0")
            self.slide_interval = slide_interval
            self.images = None
            self.imagenes2 = None
            self.set_images(images)
            self.set_images2(imagenes2)
            self.slide2 = tkinter.Label(self)
            self.slide2.pack()
            self.slide = tkinter.Label(self)
            self.slide.pack()
            
   
        def set_images(self, images):
            self.images = cycle(images)
        def set_images2(self, imagenes2):
            self.imagenes2 = cycle(imagenes2)     
                def set_image(self):
           
            self.image_name = next(self.images)
            self.image_name2 = next(self.imagenes2)
            print(self.imagenes2)
            print(self.images)
            filename, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image_name)
            filename, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image_name2)
            self.image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.image_name))
            self.Imagen_2 = Label(self.master, image= self.image1)
            self.image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.image_name2))
            self.imagen_4 = Label(self.master, image= self.image2)
        def main(self):
            """Display the images"""
            self.set_image()
            self.slide.config(image=self.image1)
            self.slide.place(x=23,y=70)
            self.slide2.config(image=self.image2)
            self.slide2.place(x=605,y=5)
            self.title(self.image_name)
            #self.center()
            self.after(self.slide_interval, self.start)
        
        def start(self):
            """Start method"""
            self.main()
            self.mainloop()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        slide_interval = 5000
        
        
       
        import glob
        images = glob.glob("*.png")
        imagenes2 = glob.glob("*.gif")
       
        path = "PDFS/"
            
      
                    
        exts = ["png","bmp"]#, "bmp", "png", "gif", "jpeg"]
        exts2 = ["gif","bmp"]
        images = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in exts)]
        imagenes2 = [fn2 for fn2 in os.listdir(path) if any(fn2.endswith(ext2) for ext2 in exts2)]

        # Empieza el slideShow
        slideshow = Slideshow(images,imagenes2, slide_interval)
        slideshow.start()
except:
    print("No")´´´
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya está resuelto, lo que estaba fallando era la ruta, que se pone mal por el visual studio code y no da pillado donde esta realmente algunos archivos aunque algunos me los detectase asique el cambio que hice es este por si alguno le pasa lo mismo que a mi:
`path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('vuestro path')`
y  con eso se soluciono mi problema, pero cuidado que creo que marca la capeta anterior o eso es lo que me pasa a mi no se porqué